# Upgrade from Caixa Mágica 22LTS (based on Ubuntu 14.04) to Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.04?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04

I have Caixa Mágica 22LTS (based on Ubuntu 14.04) installed on my laptop. I want to know if is possible to convert it to Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.04 (in Portuguese). If yes, then I need to install the HP OfficeJet 7500A, which I can't install with my Caixa Mágica.

Comment: To convert to Ubuntu fresh install Ubuntu, yes.

Comment: This is not off-topic, as the OP's goal is explicitly to get Ubuntu running, which we support. They are trying to run Ubuntu instead of the other non-Ubuntu OS currently being used. This question--and [the answer that has been posted](https://askubuntu.com/a/613869/22949)--are valuable and on-topic for our site.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you can't upgrade.

Long answer: I think there is a confusion in your mind. Please, allow me to clear that for you.

Your distribution Caixa Mágica 22LTS is **based on** Ubuntu 14.04, which means, it is a **different** distribution. Even if they have a lot in common - Ubuntu can be considered the "parent" distro for Caixa Mágica, from the moment when "daughter" distro - in your case, Caixa - split up from the "parent" distro, - in this case, Ubuntu - , they all evolve on different paths.

Maybe you'd find easier to understand that, if you'd think about the Biology class and the evolution of species - well, in Linux world, things are pretty much the same.

If you need to upgrade, then you should upgrade your distribution Caixa Mágica 22LTS to its last stable version. If you want to use Ubuntu instead, then forget about Caixa Mágica and do a fresh Ubuntu install.

But **under no circumstances**, don't make the mistake to upgrade your older version of Caixa Mágica to the newer version of Ubuntu! Because if you do so, you risk messing up everything. The resulting "distro" would be neighter Caixa Mágica, nor Ubuntu. That **if** it will be functional!

I'll give you another example, just to show you that you are not the only non-Ubuntu user "lurking" on Askubuntu. I use Zorin OS 6 Core, a distro which is based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Now that Ubuntu 14.04 is already released, I keep getting messages from the system asking me to do the upgrade to Ubuntu14.04. But **I don't** upgrade, I ignore the messages. Why? Because, like I've said, I know that Ubuntu and Zorin OS are two different distributions.

Still, coming here, in the very hart of Ubuntu community is the best thing that any user of Ubuntu-derived distros can do, as long as he/she keeps in mind the way Linux distributions relate, what they have in common, what makes them different, what are the characteristics of a specific distribution, etc.